# Trouble with REGEXP_REPLACE in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb, regexp-replace

I recently upgraded to MySQL 8 so that I can use the new Regular Expression functions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) to clean up a lot of bad addresses.  However, I'm running into trouble using REGEXP_REPLACE.

I'm starting by running a SELECT query as an example (so I can see what's going on before I run an UPDATE query):

```
SELECT address1_raw, CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE (address1_raw, '^[0-9]+ ', '') 
USING UTF8) as replaced,
CONVERT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(address1_raw, '^[0-9]+ ') USING UTF8) as captured
FROM members WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (address1_raw, '^[0-9]+ ');
```

The results I'm looking for are like this:

```
address1_raw | replaced  | captured
54 Main St   | Main St   | 54
1089 High St | High St   | 1089
67 Broadway  | Broadway  | 67
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
address1_raw | replaced               | captured
54 Main St   | Main St                | 54
1089 High St | Main StHigh St         | 1089
67 Broadway  | Main StHigh StBroadway | 67
```

I'm totally stumped! Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Provide example data on https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: Hi Raymond - do you mean additional data to the above?

Comment: i mean the source data indeed.

Comment: I hope this is helpful: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xvUmKyJVrnbeRGfw3ts6U9/0 - but one note, it doesn't seem to be recognizing the REGEXP_REPLACE function even though I set it to MySQL 8

Comment: @rkm2 - MySQL 8.0 is still warm around the gills.  File a bug report at bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: @rkm2 - What version are you using?  There was an "Incompatible change" in 8.0.4; see the changelog.

Comment: Thanks Rick.  I'm using 8.0.11.  Thanks for the bug report link - I just checked and it looks like someone else just reported the same issue: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90803

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this issue, the bug has apparently been fixed in 8.0.12 - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90803