# mysql regex_replace : how to use regex group in replacement

Tags: mysql, regex

Have a table:

```
| id |      Name       |
|----------------------|
| 1  |test1 test1 test1|
| 2  |test2 test2 test2|
```

Want to select 1st regex group (used 1st word to simplify), so my query:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(name, "^([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]].*$","$1") FROM table;
```

Result:

```
|test1      |
|test1test2 |
```

So how it comes that result is accumulated? And how to avoid it and still be able to use regex group?

**UPD**: 
Mysql version:  8.0.11, MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: If you need to remove all after the first whitespace, why not use `regexp_replace(name, "(?s)\\s.*","")`? If there must be at least 1 letter or digit before, use `regexp_replace(name, "(?s)(?<=[[:alnum:]])\\s.*","")`. Also, are you sure the replacement backreference syntax is a dollar+number? Try `"\\1"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that's just an example, question in "HOW TO USE REGEX GROUP" in replacement, and I've tried \\1 it's just treated as "1".
But to add  with "1" result will be "1" for 1st row, and "11" for second!
it's also accumulated, and I don't get why :(

Comment: I admit this is not expected and is possibly a bug, but what version of MySQL are you using? I understand it is MySQL 8.x, but maybe it is a test build?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988101/trouble-with-regexp-replace-in-mysql-8

Comment: It's not "$1" it's "\\1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90803 - May 21:

> Fixed in 8.0.12.
>
> REGEXP_RELACE() results from one result set row could carry forward
> to the next row, resulting in accumulation of previous results in the
> current row.

Comment: yupp, it should to be, had no chance to check yet

Comment: seems 8.0.12 still not released, have you tried to install it?