# MySQL REGEX - Extract Data from String

Tags: mysql, regex

I am stuck... I have a field (Description) in MySQL with a very long string. Embedded in that string is a reference number that I need to extract to another field using a view. The string will look something like this.

> LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT INTEGER NEC ODIO XX00000000X LIBERO SED CURSUS ANTE DAPIBUS DIAM SED NISI NULLA QUIS SEM AT NIBH ELEMENTUM IMPERDIET

What I need from that string is XX00000000X. It always starts with two letters, numbers in the middle and ends with a letter.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Description, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX (Description, ' ',  (Description REGEXP '[[:upper:]]{1,2}[[:digit:]]+[[:upper:]]$') * -1 ) AS Reference 
FROM db_test.tbl_regex;
```

The problem is that it only collects the Reference data when it is at the end of the Description field.

Comment: MySQL has no built in regex replacement/extraction capabilities.  Can you be more specific about the string you are trying to match?  For example, is it always preceded or followed by one or more strings which might serve as markers?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using it in `SUBSTRING_INDEX`. The `REGEX` operator just returns a true/false result saying whether the string matches, not any kind of index.

Comment: You can find which rows have such data, but if you're using mysql you'll need to pluck out the reference number in your app layer.

Comment: Agree with @Bohemian, but the reason it's just finding those at the end is the $ in your regex. That matches end of line.

Comment: In MySQL, you can find rows that match the pattern, but you'll have to extract the matching value in the application layer.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments and questions. There are no string patterns that I can match to. The reference data used to be at the end of the line which made it easier using $.

Comment: I have a regex that will find it but I don't know how to translate it to MySQL.   \b[a-z,A-Z]{2}[0-9]\w+[a-z,A-Z]{1}\b

You are right the MySQL regex does not natively return strings. That is what I am using Substring_Index for. I am definitely open to alternative methods. I somewhat inherited this challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR()` was introduced in MariaDB 10.0.5 and MySQL 8.0.

That is what you need to locate and extract the XX00000000X.

`REGEXP` (as you used it) only returns true/false.  `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` needs the string.

If you can't upgrade to one of those, the best you can do is use `REGEXP` to identify rows that have XX00000000X, then use your app code to extract it.

Comment: This is a big help. From what I see in the documentation, v8.0 was just released in April. The version history jumps from 5.7 to 8.0 so I will be looking to my host to update in the near future.

Comment: Yes, 8.0.11 is hot off the presses.  And there is already a bug in a related routine - `REGEXP_REPLACE`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247765/mysql-regex-replace-how-to-use-regex-group-in-replacement/50498472?noredirect=1#comment88021144_50498472